# Opengl bitmap font on intel video card cause memory leak

Tags: opengl, fonts, bitmap

I noticed that bitmap font using opengl rendering on Intel video card always causes memory leak. The memory keeps growing everytime the font rendering is called. Does not matter windows GUI program or console program. I recently tried NeHe's bitmap font program lesson13.cpp as in  [NeHe bitmap font tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bitmap_fonts/17002/)

This program only needs 9MB memory on non-intel display card and is very stable. However on Intel video card, it keeps growing at a rate of 4MB/s.

my video card is Intel HD family and also the same on other Intel video cards. If uses OutlineFont, there is no problem. However, the outline font does not look great. Anyone has notice this problem with bitmap font and can anyone give me a solution or workaround?

Comment: You are not going to like this, but... if you want to write portable code you should avoid doing that. It relies on **1.** Display Lists and **2.** WGL bitmap fonts. Both of which are deprecated, display lists directly and WGL bitmap fonts indirectly (they rely on OpenGL's old raster API). The best thing to do would be to pursue texture mapped fonts, and you are in luck because NeHe has a [tutorial for that too](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/2d_texture_font/18002/).

Comment: Thanks Andon for the information. The texture mapped font does not have the memory leakage problem. However I am still having some trouble to use it so far. It has several problems: 1. hard to get fonts needed. 2. The font background is not transparent and would bring a filled rectangle to the figure.